# Activate target membership for a custom font in Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, fonts

Searching for a reason why a custom font does not work can be really *nerve racking!*
One possible **issue** could be to **not** **include** the **font** in the **target** **membership** in Xcode

How do I include the custom font correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to select the font and select the target Membership checkmark for your app as seen in the picture.

[image: Xcode window with selected target membership for the custom font]

Comment: What should we do if ticking the box is not available?

Comment: These controls may not be available. The problem is more hideous Apple UI: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52958090/missing-target-membership-panel-in-xcode10